# <iframe> works locally until I upload to apache server

Tags: html, apache

I have built a page with an  tag to display another page. When testing locally everything works as intended until I upload it to my apache2 server. I've never had this issue before. I have pulled older versions of this page that I know have worked before and they no longer work on the new software(switched from arch to Ubuntu server). Below is the code I used for the .

```
<iframe src="IP_Adress_Here" style="height:100%; max-height:3000px; border-radius: 12px;" width="100%" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: What is the full URL of the server you want to use in the iframe? I think you need the full URL e.g. `https://example.com/some/page.html`.  Also to note, if that IP address is pointing to your local IP address, this would only work if your server is open to the public at that IP address. e.g. `127.0.0.1` or `192.168.x.y` won't work.

Comment: Is it for a minecraft plugin called dynmap and The iframe connects through a domain. I have done this same thing before and still have never seen this happen before.

Comment: What is the iframe `src` you are using? feel free to hide the details with `x` characters. e.g. `https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/some/path/page.html`

Comment: http://xxx.xxx:xxx

Comment: Are you on Twitter? DM me ( https://twitter.com/scunliffe ) the url you are pointing to (I promise I won’t share it) so I can test it and help debug this.

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone interested, the issue was that the wrapping page is being served up on HTTPS but the iframe content was on HTTP and the browser’s security model blocked the loading of the iframe content (shows quietly as an error in the console)